# the coins for testnet were not sent to my wallet

Tags: testnets

I am participating in testnet for Alchemy (GOERLI FAUCET), connected my Metamask wallet and claimed the coins, but did't receive anything. The platform though send me a "you will be able to claim the coins again in 24h" message.
Am I doing smth wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Were you logged in with Alchemy at the moment of call? Strange though, you probabbly should wait until funds are added to your wallet, it sometimes happens.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm weird, you should try pinging [Alchemy's Discord](https://discord.com/invite/frSF7J8Ktw) or support@alchemy.com. But normally, you get it into your wallet pretty instanteously. That 24h message was probably because they have limits to prevent bots but you can get more every 24h.

Were you using their official faucet - https://goerlifaucet.com/